# .Net C# It´s posible customize the Windows Login Screen?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-logon

Is there any possibility of creating a program / client that shows an interface where you can see a QR code generated by that program in the Window´s login screen?

I have seen that there is an application called StrongPass PC Logon, which does something similar to what I would like to do.
When installing the program for the computer it seems that it runs a WindowsForms app (or so it seems) before logging into Windows and this "enables" a qr scanning option.

I'm not interested in how the program works, I would just like to know how I can make a program that show / edit the login screen in windows without compromising the security of the system.
[Like in this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7HHh.png)

I made a small WindowsForms application that generated a QR and this was displayed in a pictureBox, then by editing the registry editor, adding utilman.exe and a string value, I put the path to the executable and got the app interface displayed on the screen login, but there should be other more effective ways to do it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am looking to be able to do it with updated versions of windows (10 or 11).